# PHP and MySQL - display form based on date and time

Tags: php, mysql, forms, timestamp

I need help understanding how to display content/forms based on the server's current date/time.

I have 10 questions stored in a table. The questions are called up and displayed using PHP, with a form next to each question (to gather the answer).  Each question has a "due date" associated with it.

Whenever the page is called, I want to show a form, but only next to the questions that haven't passed the due date. All additional questions should still display, but any questions with a date/time in the past should not display the form - only the previously entered answer.

Comment: example please? i didn't understand.

Answer (score 0):

In question table, you must have asked_date (or what ever column's name) for validation. It's used for validation.

So, in php code you just validate with:

```
if($question['asked_date'] != date('d-m-Y')){ hideForm(); }
```

I'm quoting this question:

> (all questions should still display, but any questions with a
>   date/time in the past should not display the form.. only the
>   previously entered answer).

Answer (score 0):

> **time()** is the function you are looking for. It returns the current timestamp.

So when you start the questions, first time, you need to set a timestamp in you mysql such as

```
$endtime=time()+60*60*1; //1 hour from the current time
$sql="UPDATE questions SET endtime='$endtime'";
```

When you are checking for questions, just add a condition such as,

```
if($row["endtime"]>time()){ 
    //Load everything
}
else{
    //Load only questions and answers removing the buttons
}
```

*But I strongly suggest the use of jquery and ajax for better user experience.*